# Create Stormpath user and assign to group in one call

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath

I'd like to submit the user creation request with the group but not sure how to do that in express-stormpath.

Right now I use the pre- and post-registration handlers to get a field, delete it from formData, pass to res, then set the group on the post registration handler:

```
preRegistrationHandler: function (formData, req, res, next) {
    res.locals.describes = formData.describes;
    delete formData.describes;

    next();
},

postRegistrationHandler: function (account, req, res, next) {
    var seekerHref = config.SEEKERS_HREF;
    var employerHref = config.EMPLOYERS_HREF;

    if (res.locals.describes === "seeker") {
        //Adding to seeker group
        account.addToGroup(seekerHref, function(err, membership) {
            console.log(membership);
        });
    } else if (res.locals.describes === "employers") {
        //Adding to the employer group
        account.addToGroup(employerHref, function(err, membership) {
            console.log(membership);
        });
    }
    delete res.locals.describes;

    next();
}
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea. What happens if the connection becomes unavailable and the group assignment fails? The user might be stuck in a limbo state without a group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternate way of doing this is to save the value to the account's Custom Data object, and then use that to create the group afterwards.

express-stormpath will save a form field to Custom Data automatically if you define it in the [form configuration](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/registration.html#creating-custom-fields):

```
web: {
  register: {
    form: {
      fields: {
        describes: {
          enabled: true,
          label: 'Position',
          name: 'describes',
          placeholder: 'e.g. employer, seeker',
          required: true,
          type: 'text'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your post-registration handler, retrieve the Custom Data value and use it to assign the group:

```
postRegistrationHandler: function (account, req, res, next) {
    var seekerHref = config.SEEKERS_HREF;
    var employerHref = config.EMPLOYERS_HREF;

    account.getCustomData(function(err, customData) {
        if (customData.describes === "seeker") {
            //Adding to seeker group
            account.addToGroup(seekerHref, function(err, membership) {
                console.log(membership);
            });
        } else if (customData.describes === "employers") {
            //Adding to the employer group
            account.addToGroup(employerHref, function(err, membership) {
                console.log(membership);
            });
        }

        customData.remove('describes');
        customData.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    });

    next();
}
```

This way, you are guaranteed that the value will be saved. If the post-registration handler fails for some reason, you can see what group the user should be in by examining the account's custom data resource.

Comment: I had thought about doing that and I will now. I suppose I can also check on the post login handler and if the user doesn't have a group at that point I can set it again and if that fails, log it and log them out and redirect to a page to contact us. Thanks Nate.

Comment: Also just realised you work at Stormpath - this is great software guys, you've taken the one thing that I hate doing and done it ever so beautifully. I would maybe request that in future we should be able to assign group on registration, much like when you create the account in the Stormpath console.

Comment: We <3 customer feedback @ Stormpath.  If you would like to propose ideas, Stormpath has a feature enhancement portal here: ideas.stormpath.com

Comment: @OmarMir Really appreciate your feedback!